# Java project & storing SQL queries in XML file similar to Android with ADT plugin

Tags: java, android, sql, eclipse, adt

I need a way to store SQL queries inside a xml file inside my java project. Need it to be similar to mechanism used when developing for Android using Eclipse + the ADT plugin: where you can have the queries as  resources inside a xml file in "res/values" folder & access them in code by R.string.QUERY_NAME.

**Is there a tool/plugin for either Eclipse or Netbeans to perform such task?**

I am using ormlite library, but some queries which are more complex can't be/are difficult to reached just by its API

Or is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyBatis / iBatis uses XML for queries. Whether it fits is up-to-you.

Answer (score 0):

hi am not aware how adt works. But we are maintaining our sql scripts in project itself in XML files. And using liquibase to take care of the executions.
By this we can also maintain proper database versions relevant to out specific branch.

Please look in the the link. http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart.html